# 2nd greatest among 4 numbers...iam getting the error as "expected : before )"

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
```

iam not getting the output it is showing expected : before )

```
int main() {

      int a,b,c,d,k;
      scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);//input
      k=(((a>b && a>c && a>d) ? (((b>c && b>d) ? b : ((c>b && c>d) ? c:d)))) : ((b>a && b>c && b>d) ? (((a>c && a>d) ? a : ((c>a && c>d) ? c:d)))) :  (((c>a && c>b && c>d) ? (((a>b && a>d) ? a : ((b>a && b>d) ? b:d)))) : ((d>a && d>b && d>c) ? (((a>b && a>c) ? a : ((b>c && b>a) ? b:c))))));
      printf("%d",k);
      return 0;}
```

Comment: Yep, one of your ternary operators is clearly missing the colon and second operand. You can clearly see it when you read that line. So just fix it. And probably already realized this kind of code should never be written.

Comment: sir please correct it sir

Comment: sir all ternary operators are present sir

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I fixed it. See answer below. Think i got eye-cancer now

Comment: Simple solution: **do not write such code**. Intermediate solution: Use a modern (i.e. one that was at least modern 10 years ago) editor which provides parenthesis highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought ternary operators were some kind of **eye-candy**.
This really reminds me of some sort of eye-cancer (no offense).

---

### Better solution (with any count of variables)

If I'm right you want to extract the second greatest number from `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` and save it in `k`.
Try this:

```
int compare_int(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    int int_a = *((int*)a);
    int int_b = *((int*)b);

    if (int_a == int_b)
        return 0;
    else if ( int_a < int_b )
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int value[4];

    // set values in any order:
    value[0] = 20; //second greatest
    value[1] = -36;
    value[2] = 294;
    value[3] = 3;

    qsort(value, 4, sizeof(int), compare_int);

    // now the array is sorted by value.
    // tho the second greatest number is in value[2].
    printf("%d\n", value[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Reformatting your code

Nevertheless.. I reformatted your code a bit:

```
k = (((a > b && a > c && a > d) ? (((b > c && b > d) ? b : ((c > b && c > d) ? c : d)))) : ((b > a && b > c && b > d) ? (((a > c && a > d) ? a : ((c > a && c > d) ? c : d)))) : (((c > a && c > b && c > d) ? (((a > b && a > d) ? a : ((b > a && b > d) ? b : d)))) : ((d > a && d > b && d > c) ? (((a > b && a > c) ? a : ((b > c && b > a) ? b : c))))));
```

Is the same as:

```
k = (
        // misplaced (
            (a > b && a > c && a > d) ?
            (
                (
                    (b > c && b > d) ? b :
                    (
                        (c > b && c > d) ? c : d
                    )
                )
            )
        // misplaced )
        :
        // misplaced (
            (b > a && b > c && b > d) ?
            (
                (
                    (a > c && a > d) ? a :
                    (
                        (c > a && c > d) ? c : d
                    )
                )
            )
        // misplaced )
        :
        (
            // misplaced (
                (c > a && c > b && c > d) ?
                (
                    (
                        (a > b && a > d) ? a :
                        (
                            (b > a && b > d) ? b : d
                        )
                    )
                )
            // misplaced )
            :
            (
                (d > a && d > b && d > c) ?
                (
                    (
                        (a > b && a > c) ? a :
                        (
                            (b > c && b > a) ? b : c
                        )
                    )
                )
                // missing
                // :
                // (
                //     expression
                // )
            )
        )
    );
```

> Easy huh?
>   Now you can see that you are even misplaced some `(`'s and `)`'s and also several `:`'s

Comment: StackOverflow: Matching parentheses for those who can't do it themselves since 2008.